# Error formato "datepicker" JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-datepicker

Buenas este es mi campo para ingresar una fecha de vacaciones, pero el formato por defecto está como dd month,yyyy (27 September,2018).

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="input-field col s4">
  <input type="date" class="datepicker" id="fechainivac" onchange="fnlimpiarvacaciones()" style="color: black;" value=" ">
    <label style="color: black;" for="Fecha Inicio Vacaciones">Fecha Inicio Vacaciones</label>
</div>
```

Utilicé un código javascript para cambiar el formato pero sigue sin cambiar nada:

```
$(function() {
  $('#fechainivac').datepicker({dateFormat:'dd-mm-yyyy'});
});
```

Alguna idea para hacer el cambio de formato, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que [tengas escrito correctamente el formato que buscas](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp). Y cambia los inputs de tipo text. Que se encima con el input date de HTML.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#fechainivac').datepicker({dateFormat:'dd-MM-yy'});
  $('#fechainivac2').datepicker({dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="fechainivac"style="color: black;">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="fechainivac2"style="color: black;">
```